# javascript file not loading

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Trying to import my js file from my page.

My page is in `webcontent/mydomain/templates/page.xhtml`

My js is in `webcontent/mydomain/test/scripts`

In page.xhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../test/scripts/test.js"></script>
```

But still the script is not getting picked.

Can anyone tell how I need to give the path in src.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq && http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: try the full path `<script src="c:/....mydomain/test/scripts/test.js"></script>`

Comment: Try: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./test/scripts/test.js"></script>`

Comment: You REALLY need to show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `webcontent` is the root of public web content and thus `/mydomain` is also a public folder and thus your JavaScript is standalone available by `http://localhost:8080/context/mydomain/test/scripts/test.js`, assuming a domain of `http://localhost:8080` and a context path of `/context`, then the following should do:

```
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/mydomain/test/scripts/test.js"></script>
```

This will generate a domain-relative URL with a dynamically inlined context path, which is much more robust than fiddling with `../` which would make the URI relative to the current request URI (as you see in browser's address bar) and not to the physical location of the template file as many starters incorrectly assume.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script src="/test/scripts/test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you open your page from the server, not a file?

Comment: I am using JSF2.0 so only xhtml. Also I can not use h:outputScript as i cann not place the js in resources folder. Will the below code still work "<script src="/test/scripts/test.js"></script>... I am using JSF2.0 so only xhtml. Also I can not use h:outputScript as i cann not place the js in resources folder. Will the below code still work "<script src="/test/scripts/test.js"></script>